# No X to delete reading list

Tags: macos

On my Macbook Pro OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 I have a problem with the reading list. I can hide it that works. The problem is how do I edit to delete some on the reading lists. There USED TO BE A SMALL  X  IN THE RIGHT HAND CORNER. I could click it to delete it, but no more. Yes the software is up to date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the item in the list and choose Remove Item.